# Understanding how to classify EEG Signals in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

I want to create a tool that classifies EEG signals and reports abnormalities, however I am having trouble sorting out which tools would be the best to create such an application. First, which machine learning platform to use, (Neural Networks, Classification Learner App, Wavelet Transform, etc, etc). Second how do I analyze the EEG scans and import them into datasets (Brainstorm, Fieldtrip, toolboxes etc). Any help would be greatly appreciated, as I am new to Matlab Machine Learning, but I am very enthusiastic about the product and the possibilities of Matlab. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a great research project! When I was completing my PhD at Linköping University, two of my colleagues published this great research project showing how to classify EEG Signals using Wavelet Transform. The paper can be accessed here http://liu.diva-portal.org/smash/get/diva2:746664/FULLTEXT01.pdf.

However this is not the only way to classify EEG Signals. Personally, one of my graduate students just last year decided to create an application based on a Deep Neural Network in order to classify epileptic seizures in EEG signals.

If you are importing EEG files from public databases, most of the time, the data will be in .edf format. You can create a script that can read this, and there are toolboxes for Matlab that can read these files.

The answer to your question may be one that you need to research yourself. What I mean by that is you can actually research and test the accuracy of different methods for classifying EEGs. Your results then will be able to help people in your situation.